# Robot framework: "confirm page loaded " keyword passes in one test while fails in other

Tags: robotframework, selenium2library

I have two separate robot testcases.
Each of them has the following common Testcases and keywords:

```
*** Test Cases ***

Login to apinf
  confirm page loaded   Users
  Go to login
  Login to apinf    asdas   asdasd
  confirm page loaded   Users

*** Test Cases ***
Go to login
  Click Element     id=frontpage-button
  confirm page loaded   Users
  Click Element id=signin-button
  confirm page loaded   Login
```

When I ran all the test suits together using a shell, the first suite containing the above testcases and keywords passes the `confirm page loaded   Users` keyword.
However in the second suite, `confirm page loaded   Users` is failed, hence it displays the following error message in the log:

> No keyword with name 'confirm page loaded' found.

The screenshot for the **passed testcase** is below:
["confirm page loaded..." passes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgMNL.png)

screenshot where the keyword was not found is below:
["confirm page loaded..." was not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53aad.png)

I am using the Selenium2Library which is defined in both files.

Can someone please help me to figure out why the keyword passed in one suite and can't be found in another?

Thanks

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of logs. Take the time to copy, paste, and format the relevant information in the body of your question.

Comment: If you're getting a "keyword not found" message, that just means that you haven't imported the library or resource file which has that keyword.

Comment: Hi @Brylan, Thanks for the scrrenshot tips. However the log was from report.html that is generated when the tests finnish execution. I felt providing the screenshots would be better for anyone to look what's going on in the system.

In any case, both testcases have the following declared in the beginning:

`*** Settings ***`
`Library  Selenium2Library`
`Suite Setup  Go to homepage`
`Suite Teardown  Close All Browsers`

Still one suite is failing and another is passing. 
SO I assume the resource file is working as it should be.

Comment: FYI, checked the framework version from terminal:

**Robot Framework 3.0.4 (Python 2.7.10 on darwin)**

Comment: Also with "pip freeze" command, I checked the selenium version and found the following:
**robotframework-selenium2library==3.0.0**
**robotframework-seleniumlibrary==3.1.1**

Comment: None of what you said in the last three comments matter. Unless your test imports a library with the keyword "confirm page loaded", it's going to fail, and `confirm page loaded` is not a standard keyword provided by Selenium2Library. This is very simple: if robot can't find it, you either have a typo or you're not importing it.